# Webpack 3.5.5 module.exports = function : Config did not export an object

Tags: webpack

I believe webpack@3.5.5 supports returning a function from webpack.config.js. When I try it and I try to pass `--env.foo=1` I keep getting 
`Config did not export an object`.

Here's my whole webpack.config.js but I imagine it's only the last line that matters. What could be wrong with this?

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/js');
PROD = 1
var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.min.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      include: APP_DIR,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'] //, 'react-hmre']
      }
    }]
  }
};

module.exports = function (env){return config};
```

I already had the config object working (truncated it for the purpose of the question) but now trying to pass in CLI args I have to export a function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack@3.5.5 was installed in global but not in the local project. I concluded this was the issue after creating a separate project to reproduce the error and found it was not reproduced once I installed 3.5.5 in local.